oVirt ansible create VM doesn't get a IPv4
Trying to create a new VM in OLVM / oVirt 4.4 using the ansible collection using the vm_infra role. All runs with no errors but the VM never gets an IPV4 address.
yml config looks like this,
--- 


###########################
# Common
###########################
olvm_cluster: Default
guest_dns_servers: 'XXX.XX.X.20 XXXX.XX.XX.20'
guest_dns_search: test.com
guest_timezone: "GMT+01:00"

###########################
# Profiles/Templates
###########################

db_vm:
  template: OL8U9_x86_64-olvm-b219
  cluster: Default
  memory: 4GiB
  cores: 1
  storage_domain : Datastore1_UAT
  cloud_init:
    timezone: "{{ guest_timezone }}"
    dns_servers: "{{ guest_dns_servers }}"
    dns_search: "{{ guest_dns_search }}"
    nic_name: eth0                                
    nic_boot_protocol: static                     
    nic_netmask: 255.255.255.192                    
    nic_on_boot: True                           
 
  nics:
      - name: nic1                                
        network: ovirtmgmt                         
        profile_name: ovirtmgmt  
        interface: virtio  
     
###########################
# Guests
###########################
vms:
  - name: xxxxxxxxxxx78
    state: present 
    description: this is a test 123
    profile: "{{ db_vm }}"    
    cloud_init:
      host_name: xxxxxxxxx78
      nic_ip_address: 1XX.1XX.183.12

Anyone have a working example of creating a new VM on OLVM / oVirt in ansible with the vm_infra role that uses a static IPv4 in the ovirtmgmt network?
I can get this to work from the UI so the overall environment works fine. It's just when I do it from ansible I have a problem. I can't get the IPV4 address I want assigned, same for the other clound_init values.
